# mysql select from two tables where user is the owner

Tags: mysql

My MySQL knowledge is kind of limited when it comes to selecting from two tables.

What I have is one table with details of files a user has uploaded, so for example it contains these columns:

```
id, fileId, userId, uploadTime, fileName
```

I also have another table that contains information on who downloaded files and when, and it contains the following:

```
id, userId, fileId, downloadTime
```

What I need to do is count the number of times a specific users files were downloaded, but I'm not sure how, would it be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM downloadTable WHERE fileId IN (SELECT fileId, userId FROM userTable WHERE userId = 5)
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The SubQuery should return only one field. In your case, it is the `fileId`. Change your SQL to:

```
SELECT * FROM `downloadTable`
   WHERE `fileId` IN (
      SELECT `fileId` FROM `userTable` WHERE `userId` = 5
   )
```

This selects the downloaded files where the `fileId` are owned by the `userId` with `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JOIN:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM downloadTable d
INNER JOIN userTable u
    ON d.userId = u.userId
WHERE u.userId = 5
```

This links the records in both tables in such a way that the `userId` columns are consistent across them both, for this query. Then you just specify a constraint on the `userId` and it will spill over into the `downloadsTable` as well.

This is better than a subquery because it will run faster - JOINs are (in most cases) the way you'll want to link your data when querying.